# How to update billing information for a Flex Token?

Tags: cybersource

Currently, I'm working with 2 apps where user can generate a payment token associated with their account. 1 uses the Secure Acceptance Hosted Checkout and the other uses Flex Microform. 1 possible case involves the user's card being captured via the Microform and then later updated via the Hosted Checkout.

[The docs](https://developer.cybersource.com/api/developer-guides/dita-flex/SAFlexibleToken/FlexAPI/tokenize_card.html) mention being able to replace the billing info associated with the Flex token, but it's unclear the mechanism available. I'm aware that the Hosted Checkout supports updating this info, but it's preferred to make the update without prompting the user via the Hosted Checkout so the user never needs to see the default address or require putting in their address twice. Is there an endpoint that can be uses to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the intended way of doing things for cybersource, But there is a soap service named "paySubscriptionUpdateService" in the simple order (soap) api that allowed me update the name & address on a token generated via the flex api.

You can take a look at the simple order API documentation on cybersource website - chapter 7 "Updating a subscription"
https://developer.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Recurring_Billing/SO_API/Recurring_Billing_SO_API.pdf

I'm sure there is a way through rest API too, I'm not sure how to do it yet. I'll circle back if I see something

Comment: The Simple Order API works for the question posed and later became a consideration. However, if wanting the billing info to pass an address verification check before being accepted, there didn't appear to be a good solution. SO API only runs AVS when creating a subscription. It was later clarified that Flex is more geared for 1-time payments. With those points in mind, the solution ended up being using HC in place of Flex. The newer version of Flex supports TMS, which I think is the REST way of doing this, but requires a migration.

Comment: @XhkUnlimit Is there a way to do this through their REST API?